# iOS - NSLocalizedString is only returning the key string

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, nslocalizedstring

I'm having some trouble debugging my `NSLocalizedString` implementation. Should be simple, but whatever I do, the function only returns the `KEY` string.

I'm using XCode 4.5 and iOS6, so I:

1. Added a new file called `File.strings`.
2. In my project settings I added English and Spanish as language settings.
3. Clicked "Make Localized" in the file inspector, and made sure that both English and Spanish options were selected, and also that the Target membership to my target was selected.
4. Added `"KEY" = "TestEnglish";` to my english `File.strings`
5. Added `"KEY" = "TestSpanish";` to my spanish `File.strings`
6. Added `NSLog(@"Localization: %@\n", NSLocalizedString(@"KEY", nil));` to my `.m` file.

When I run the app, the value `"KEY"` is always displayed printed in the `NSLog`.

To jump into this a bit more, I tried this as well:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"en" ofType:@"lproj"];
NSString *str = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:path] localizedStringForKey:@"KEY" value:@"" table:nil];
NSLog(@"Localization: %@\n", str);
```

and still the value `"KEY`" is printed, yet, `path` is a valid path.

Does anyone have any clue how to debug this? I feel like I've read every SO question/answer out there, but none of the suggestions help.

I realize that `NSLocalizedString` returns the `KEY` string when it cannot match a key, but I don't see how I can debug why my app might not be matching the KEY.

I've also deleted/cleaned the app about a dozen times.

Comment: Should not `table:nil` be `table:@"File"` instead?

Comment: @H2CO3: Wow, yes, thank you. That grabs the english version, and I'm super glad that works. But ultimately, I need NSLocalizedString to work so that I can use the convenience of that method. Do I need to rename "File.strings" to something else to get NSLocalizedString to work maybe???

Comment: you shall put all the localizations you expect to have access to into "XXX.lproj/Localized.strings". Also, why do you **have to** use `NSLocalizedString()`?

Comment: I certainly don't have to use NSLocalizedString, but I would eventually like several languages, and NSLocalizedString makes sense. It appears (thanks to your comments), that the strings file must be named Localized.string in order for NSLocalizedString macro to find it. I just found that NSLocalizedStringFromTable is another macro which will allow me to change the file name if I wanted to keep it as File.strings. Thanks for your help! Put this in a formal answer, and I'll accept it. Cheers!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you specify `table:nil`, then `NSBundle` will try to fetch the localization from the default table (the one in `SOMELANG.lproj/Localizable.strings`). If you have the localization elsewhere, you should explicitly specify the table using `table:@"File"` (or use the `NSLocalizedStringFromTable()` macro in a similar manner:

```
NSString *value = NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"key", @"File", nil);
```

Answer (score 1):

Rename the InfoPlist.strings file to Localizable.strings (double clic) and then you will get the correct string for that key.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was with the case of the string:
"bla.bla.blabla.Book**S**lot" whereas the Localizable.strings had it defined as "bla.bla.blabla.Book**s**lot"

So, double-check that the key string is in the correct case. Better yet, copy-paste.

Comment: @Warpzit, in his case - maybe. I'm just pointing out the keys are case sensitive.

Comment: You are saying I had the issue with X = X... That is not an issue, now if you said in my case X != Y. That would make sense...

Comment: Just to be clear, in my answer I have "BookSlot" vs "Bookslot" (notice the case of the letter 's' in there). So the key defined in the .strings file != the key at the call site.

Comment: I noticed and corrected my vote ;) also made it bold (needed edit something to change my vote).